# How to use Watson QA REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I generated the Question and Answer Service using the following link:

https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/04/29/using-http-adapters-to-access-watson-question-and-answer-service-at-ibm-bluemix/

However, the sample application does not work. The console error says:

> [/WatsonQA/apps/services/api/WatsonQA/common/query] exception.
>   TypeError: questionTypes is undefined.

So I tried to get questionType by calling a simple REST API using Postman. I found that calling `/v1/services` does not result in a response. I received the following message:

> No response received

I sent the following method:

`(GET) https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/question-and-answer-beta/api/v1/services`

I expected the following value:

```
{ "services": [ { "overall": 0, "dataset": "", "name": "", "description": "" } ] }
```

However, a response was not received. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you passing correct username/pwd?

Answer (score 3):

We had an issue in one of our service instance. The call should be working now.

Open a terminal and type

```
curl -u USERNAME:PASSWORD \
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/question-and-answer-beta/api/v1/services
```

Make sure you replace `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` with your service credentials.